open telemetry for exporting logs to multiple endpoint, filtering by log level for each endpoint s
I have added open telemetry for exporting logs and I configure exporter with all my endpoints. How to set loglevel for individual endpoints.
Added additional pipeline for endpoint and added Addfilter to each but the loglevel set for last endpoint is configured for all

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
